# I want to assign the one textbox value into another textbox in javascript in dynamic creation of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```js
var room = 1;
function add_fields() 
{
  room=$('#row_count').val()-1; 
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
 var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-5 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control display_name"  onkeyup="copy_data(this)" id="display_name'+room+'" name="display_name'+room+'" value="" placeholder="Display name" required /></div></div><div class="col-sm-5 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="db_value'+room+'" name="db_value'+room+'" value="" placeholder="Value" required /><input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="def_value'+room+'" name="def_value'+room+'" value=""   /></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 nopadding"><div class="input-group-btn">  <a href="javascript:;" class="btn " type="button"  onclick="remove_fields('+ room +');" title="Remove Rows"> <i class="fa fa-minus text-danger" ></i> </a></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
    $('#row_count').val(room);
 $('#pre_count').val(parseFloat($('#pre_count').val())+1);
    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
```

```html
<div class="controls" id="profs"> 
 <form class="input-append" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>dform/update_asset_options">
  <center>
   <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
    <label>Display Name</label>
         </div>
   <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
    <label>Database Value</label>
   </div> 
  </center>
  
  <input type="text" name="rowVal" id="rowVal" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="row_count" id="row_count" value="<?=$opt_count?>" />
  <input type="text" name="pre_count" id="pre_count" value="<?=$opt_count?>" />
  <? 
   //print_r($arr);die;
   $i=0;
   foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
   {
    $opt_value=explode(',',$v);
    //print_r($opt_value[1]);die;
    $display_name=$opt_value[1];
    $db_val=$opt_value[2]; 
    if($i>0)
    {
     $remClass="removeclass".$i;
    }
    else
    {
     $remClass="";
    }
    ?>
    <div class="row <?=$remClass?>" >
     <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control display_name" id="display_name<?=$i?>" name="display_name<?=$i?>" value="<?=$display_name?>" placeholder="Display Name1" required >
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-5 nopadding">
      <div class="form-group ">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="db_value<?=$i?>" name="db_value<?=$i?>" value="<?=$db_val?>" placeholder="Value" required />
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="def_value<?=$i?>" name="def_value<?=$i?>" value=""  />
      </div>
     </div>
     <?   
      if($i>0)
      {?>
       <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
         <a href="javascript:;" class="btn " type="button"  onclick="remove_fields(<?=$i?>);" title="Remove Rows"> <i class="fa fa-minus text-danger" ></i> </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      <? }
      echo "</div>";
      $i++; 
   } 
  ?>
        <div id="education_fields"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 nopadding">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
     <a href="javascript:;" class="btn " type="button"  onclick="add_fields();"title="Add Rows"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
  <center>
   <button class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" >Save</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </center>
 </form>
</div>
```

Here i have some code to create dynamic text box using add_fields(), in that i called dspname() function for assigning one text box value to another but it's not assigning to another, if i enter the name in the first textbox, the text is not copying to another textbox, how to resolve this issue can any one please help me..

Comment: If i alert rid i am getting id as always 1

Answer (score 0):

use find() to get or set value in dynamic element.
like:

```
var val1=$('#profs').find('#display_name1').val();
$('#profs').find('#display_name2').val(val1);
```

Comment: Thanku for ur reply sir, but here i am getting textbox id as always as '1' even the second textbox is created dynamically